# Is geoserver library vulnerable due to this CVE-2022-41966 which is on xstream component?

Tags: geoserver, xstream

I am using the geoserver library and geoserver internally using xstream dependency.

Due to CVE-2022-41966, is geoserver vulnerable?

Comment: If in doubt, assume yes. You should do your own analysis and not trust random strangers on the internet in security matters.

Comment: You can inspect the code base to see what's going on